# Unity - How to detect collision on child object collider

Tags: events, unity-game-engine, delegates, collision-detection

How can we make to the event "OnTriggerEnter2D" collisions on the objects children of the object with the c# event script?

Look this:

[image]

Is there any way to assign the event using "Delegates"?

Example: `myObject.EventSample += OnTriggerEnter2D`

Comment: Just to clarify: you want the OnTriggerEnter2D to be called on the "Point" object but not on the "Obstacle" object?

Comment: Not, I want this event to be called when my player touches the collider "Point"

Answer (score 0):

whether you use events or even actions of System class you will have to use a script on the "point" object to trigger it , nonetheless its your game and if you don't want to do that , I recommend that you put that collider on parent and then make the child do what you want it to do through the same script that is attached to the parent when something collides with it , I hope it makes sense . Otherwise the direct answer to your question, no it cannot be done as far as my knowledge goes unless some one increases it .Btw here is how events will work https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/events. Try them and ask if you have any problems.
Thank you ,
long live wood

Answer (score 0):

You sure can do what you suggested yourself. Let the the obstacle controller have a function like this:

```
public void ReportedTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    // Do things
}
```

Then you could put a script like this on your point object:

```
class CollisionReporter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private ObstacleController m_Controller;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    { 
        m_Controller.ReportedTriggerEnter2D(other);
    }
}
```

Be sure to assign the controller in the inspector of course.

Or an even more generic approach would be like this:

```
class CollisionReporter : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Serializable] private class TriggerEnterEvent : UnityEvent<Collider2D>{}
        [SerializeField] private TriggerEnterEvent m_OnTriggerEnter2D = new TriggerEnterEvent();

        void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
        { 
            m_OnTriggerEnter2D.Invoke(other);
        }
    }
```

With this you can assign an event handler in the inspector, similar to UI buttons.